# How to disable all views in Activity, except for specific one?

Tags: android

I have an Activity, which contains a lot of views. And I need to disable all views from user interaction, except for specific one. How can I do this in a fast way?

The only solution that I have is to disable every view manually. But there are too many views to do this. How can I make it?

Comment: Disable how? Show some code...

Comment: You could overlay a semi transparent view which blocks access to those, but it sounds like what you might want is a dialog instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are looking for way to loop in your views you can use this code :

```
ViewGroup rootView=findViewById(R.id.my_root_view_id);

        for(int i=0;i<rootView.getChildCount();i++){

            View view=rootView.getChildAt(i);

            if(view.getId()==R.id.my_specifc_view_id){

                //Do something

            }else{

                //Do something
            }

        }
```

your root View should be one of the container layouts like LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Get the root ViewGroup (such as LineairLayout) then itterate through it's children and then change the visibility

example

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById("root");
for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount();i++)
{
    View v =  (View)layout.getChildAt(i)
    // hide `v`
}
```

you also said without one, so also add an if-statement around the v variable before deleting it. in the if-statement you could check the id

Answer (score 0):

first make a list of view's id where you want to enable view like below :

```
List<Integer> viewsToEnable = new ArrayList<>();
        viewsToEnable.add(R.id.btn_save);
        viewsToEnable.add(R.id.tv_name);
        viewsToEnable.add(R.id.edt_name);
```

now check make method to enable or disable views :

```
public void enableViews(List<Integer> viewsToEnable, int parentViewResourceId) {

        ViewGroup parentView = findViewById(parentViewResourceId);

        for (int i = 0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View view = parentView.getChildAt(i);

            if (viewsToEnable.contains(view.getId())) {

                view.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                view.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    }
```

now use above method in activity or fragment :

```
enableViews(viewsToEnable,R.id.parentView);
```